# Delphi current directory database is not updating Ms Access

Tags: delphi, ms-access

I have a problem in terms on connecting my DbLogSystem.mdb to my program.

1) When I try to insert/update a record using the program, it will proceed and perform successfully,
2) When I try to reset/delete all the records using MS Access it will proceed,
But when I Run my program the data/records are still existing.

What is the possible error?

Thanks in advance.

Below is the connection string that might cause the problem:

```
mydir := GetCurrentDir;
ADOConnection_get_data.ConnectionString:= 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=puzzle33;Data Source='+ mydir +'\DbLogSystem.mdb;Persist Security Info=False';
```

or is there any method to link my .Exe program to my Database with the same path folder?

Comment: exe file located in Win32\Debug folder? may be you have two DB, one in project "root" folder (where located source file), and other one in Win32\Debug folder?

Comment: I place it with the same folder of the exe.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could just use a relative path to always link your .exe program with the database on the same folder

```
ADOConnection_get_data.ConnectionString:= 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=puzzle33;Data Source=.\DbLogSystem.mdb;Persist Security Info=False'
```

As Zam says, check that you aren't alternating with two different database at the Release and Debug folders.

Also, are you sure you are commiting your changes ?. You may be using CommitUpdates (so your changes never really arrive to the database), or you may have an active transaction that you never commit (so it's rollbacked when you exit your application).

Comment: I place the database within the same folder of the exe.
and use your given code.
I delete records manually using access but did not take effect..
what is the suggested method to this problem? thank you again.

Comment: You don't get any error ?, you just keep seeing the records deleted from Access ?. In that case you probably don't have any error but you are working with two different databases on Access and Delphi (remember that Delphi creates the Release and Debug folders, there is where your application is loading your database). Also, you may be deleting those records, but you just don't see it on Delphi, because the data is already loaded and you have to refresh it.

Comment: Basically, if your application is showing a table, and you modify that data by another app, then you'll need to reload that data on your application to see the differences (call the refresh method on your Dataset).